# How to locally re-check the data import progress of opensreetmap in Docker in remote server?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, openstreetmap, docker-machine

I was locally monitoring the progress of Docker importing openstreetmap in remote server like this:

> time docker run -v
> /home/renderaccount/zambia-latest.osm.pbf:/data.osm.pbf -v
> openstreetmap-data:/var/lib/postgresql/12/main
> overv/openstreetmap-tile-server:1.3.10 import

The network was suddenly disconnected, how to check the progress again?

local: Macos 11.6.8
remote: Ubuntu 20.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> docker logs <container_id> -f

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).